# For SEO, does it matter where the title tag is positioned within the head tag?

Tags: seo

I have always positioned my `<title>` element as the first child of the `<head>` element. I am building a site where, for various reasons the title is currently one of the last children of the `<head>` element.  Does it matter either way with regard to SEO?

Answer (score 8):

No. The value of the `<title>` tag is the value of the `<title>` tag regardless of its location in the `<head>` of the document.

Answer (score 4):

the position of title tag is irrelevant, however the position of keywords inside the title tag is important.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter where your `title` tag is in the `head`.

It does matter where you declare you `charset` though. You must declare a `charset` before a certain amount of bits within an HTML document in order for it to be valid.